# Gear up lever will not move

Tags: repair, derailleur, damage

I just got a new bike and unfortunately fell off it on the first ride, now the lever to change gear for my derailleur [Mezzu Microshift](https://www.microshift.com/models/rd-m36l/) is stuck in the position it would be if you had upped a gear before it returns to normal, and cannot be moved, is there anything that can be done?

The bike has a flat handle-bar, two levers below the handle-bar level, I think the shifter is the standard one for the derailleur its a square one that sits on the flat handlebar.

The gear down lever works fine.

[image]
Stock photo of Mezzu Microshift rear derailleur, long cage, 9 speed.

[image]
Stock photo of TS39 right-hand "thumb tap" shifter.  https://www.microshift.com/models/ts39-29/

Comment: Could you specify the type of the shifter? Flat handlebar or drop bar? What model? Aphoto could help. When you say gear up, does that mean to a smaller or to a higher sprocket? To a harder gear or to an easier gear?

Comment: flat handle bar, two levers below the handle-bar level, I think the shifter is the standard one for the derailleur its a square one that sits on the flat handlebar, and has two levers below the dial that shows the gear level from 1-8

Comment: I don't quite undertand exactly what's happening. Pictures would definitely help. Video would be even better. If the shifter and the derailleur aren't noticeably damaged, you might want to inspect the cables. Sometimes the housing can come unseated, especially in a crash, which causes shift issues that are similar to what I think you might be describing.

Comment: nothing seems damaged, and I didn't fall on that side, interestingly the lower gear lever works perfectly. I feel its either the cable or a spring somewhere.

Comment: @user37577 Oh man that's an awful thing to have happen to your new bike.  Could you please add photos of your bike showing exactly what you mean?  Some of the names are ambiguous like "lower gear lever" is that the shifter or the derailleur you're meaning ?  I've also added some stock photos of these parts as a starter, if they're wrong please [edit] and correct.

Comment: Stock photos are correct, I believe its the shifter and will replace it, it's the lever on that shifter that will not move (the smaller one in the background).